# Showing the convergence in probabilty of two Ito integrals

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-calculus

> Consider a Brownian Motion, $B(t)$, which are all $\mathcal F_t$ measurable. Let $f,f_n$ be in $L_{ad}^2\{[a,b] \times \Omega\}$, which are the set of stochastic processes that are adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}$ and satisfy $\int_a^bE\left(f(t)^2\right)dt < \infty$. Suppose that $\int_a^b|f(t)-f_n(t)|dt\to0$ almost surely. Prove that $\int_a^bf_n(t)dB(t) \to \int_a^bf_n(t)dB(t)$ in probability.

I am trying to show this two different ways. First by using $L^2$ convergence which will then imply convergence in probability. What I have for this way is the following:

Since $f$ and $f_n$ are in $L_{ad}^2$ then the ito integral $\int_a^bf(t)-f_n(t)dB(t)$ exists and $E\left|\int_a^bf(t)-f_n(t)dB(t)\right|^2=\int_a^bE\left|f(t)-f_n(t)\right|^2dt$, so it will suffice to show that the right hand side of this equal sign converges to $0$ which i'm unsure how to do.

Second, I am try to show this directly using the definition of convergence in probability.

$P\left(\left|\int_a^bf(t)-f_n(t)dB(t)\right|>\epsilon\right)\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}E\left|\int_a^bf(t)-f_n(t)dB(t)\right|$, hence if I could show that $\int_a^bf(t)dB(t) \to \int_a^bf_n(t)dB(t)$ in $L^1$ then I would be done.

Similarly,

$ P\left(\left|\int_a^bf(t)-f_n(t)dB(t)\right|>\epsilon\right)\le\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}E\left|\int_a^bf(t)-f_n(t)dB(t)\right|^2= \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\int_a^bE\left|f(t)-f_n(t)\right|^2dt$ so if we could show this last term converged to $0$ then we would be done.

Comment: For stochastic integrals $M_t := \int_a^b f(s) \, dB_s$ it holds that $\mathbb{E}(M_t)=0$, note that this does **not** imply $\mathbb{E}(|M_t|)=0$.

Comment: @saz I noticed that after I posted the question and will delete that from above, thank you though. Do you know how I should proceed with this problem?

Comment: As formulated, the statement is false. Maybe the assumption is that $\int_a^b|f(t)-f_n(t)|^2dt\to0$ a.s.?

Comment: @zhoraster then could  use the Generalized Lesbegue Dominated convergence and say $E\int_a^b|f(t)-f_n(t)|^2dt\to0$ because $\int_a^b|f(t)-f_n(t)|^2dt \le 2\int_a^b|f(t)|^2+|f_n(t)|^2dt$ and $2\int_a^b|f(t)|^2+|f_n(t)|^2dt$ is in $L^1$ since $f,f_n \in L_{ad}^2$ and if we assume $\int_a^b|f(t)-f_n(t)|^2dt\to0$ then $\int_a^b|f_n(t)|^2dt\to \int_a^b|f(t)|^2dt$ which means $2\int_a^b|f(t)|^2+|f_n(t)|^2dt \to 4\int_a^b|f(t)|^2dt$ which is also $L^1$.

Comment: I don't get your point. Currently the statement is false. You might need to edit the post.